# PAYEE_ACCOUNT_NOT_VERIFIED - PayPal Problem

Tags: rest, paypal

I have a question about users who set up a PayPal account but haven't verified it. In our system, they can start selling, but PayPal does not allow customers to buy products until the seller verifies the account(?). Is it possible to remove this limit or anything to do with it from the PayPal website so that people who set up a new account can start selling immediately and, for example, verify their account later? The question is for this error: PAYEE_ACCOUNT_NOT_VERIFIED

This is what we send (from database):
{"intent": "CAPTURE", "application_context": {"cancel_url": "XX," return_url ":"XX"}," purchase_units " : [{"invoice_id": "11-04033241 \ / 12 \ / 2021 \ / 87", "items": [{"name": "Y", "unit_amount": {"currency_code": " AUD "," value ":" 38.50 "}," quantity ":" 1 "," category ":" PHYSICAL_GOODS "}]," amount ": {" value ":" 53.50 "," currency_code ":" AUD " , "breakdown": {"item_total": {"value": "38.50", "currency_code": "AUD"}, "shipping": {"value": "15.00", "currency_code": "AUD"}} }, "payee": {"merchant_id": "XX"}, "payment_instruction": {"disbursement_mode": "INSTANT", "platform_fees": [{"amount": {"currency_code": "AUD", "value ":" 3.50 "}}]," payee ": {" merchant_id ":" XX "}}," shipping ": {" address ": {" address_line_1 ":" X "," address_line_2 ":" " , "admin_area_1": "XX", "admin_area_2": "XX", "postal_code": "XX", " country_code ":" AU "}}}]}

This is the answer from PayPal:
{"name": "NOT_AUTHORIZED", "details": [{"issue": "PAYEE_ACCOUNT_NOT_VERIFIED", "description": "Payee has not verified their account with PayPal. Your current setup requires the 'payee' to have an account with PayPal before you can process transactions on their behalf. "}]," Message ":" Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions. "," Debug_id ":" aef1250ffb618 "," links ": [{" href ":" https: / /developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYEE_ACCOUNT_NOT_VERIFIED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET "}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payee account with the `merchant_id` you specified needs to confirm their primary email [in paypal.com here](https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email).  Re-send a verification email as needed, which will have a link to verify it.

If this is sandbox, the same [can be done in a sandbox account](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email) but sandbox never sends "real" emails. Instead go to the Notifications left nav tab in the developer dashboard, to read "emails" for the sandbox accounts that belong to that developer dashboard login.

Comment: Hi,

I did some sandbox tests. I have set up accounts that are unverified and do not have a payment method attached, and yet PayPal allows them to collect payments. Accounts that register in my application should also be allowed to accept payments despite the lack of verification, which is not the case. Do you think this is a missing code on my side or is PayPal blocking such an option from its side (then why can you simulate it in a sandbox)?

Comment: A confirmed email and/or existing PayPal account is required.